# what is so special about the number $3$ in the $3n+1$ conjecture?

Tags: soft-question, collatz-conjecture, open-problem

Recently, I was quite intrigued by the [$3n+1$ conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) and it left me wondering what is so special about the number $3$? With the same rules apply, does there exist another positive integer other than $1$ such that regardless of the starting point, you seem to end hitting a certain number?

So for instance, let us take $k$ a positive integer, we start the algorithm by choosing any positive integer, say $n$, if this number is odd then multiply by $k$ and $+1$ again. If it is even then divide by $2$ as usual. Then we repeat the algorithm depending on the parity of the resulting number. So my question is that does there exist $k\geq 5$ such that given any starting point, we suspect to hit a certain number (usually $1$?) after a certain number of iterations of this algorithm?

I can see that for $k$ even, any starting point will be sent to infinity, but other than that I couldn't make any other observations.

It is just a curious thought of mine and hopefully I have explained my thought sufficiently clear. Thank you so much for help in advance!

Comment: have you done a research for generalized collatz? just google "generalized collatz"

Comment: Non-trivial cycles in other variants are well known. The usual variant has been verified particular deep , probably because it was the case Collatz invented. There is a generalization of the Collatz conjecture that has been shown to be undecidable, which already shows how difficult those sequences are to analyze.

Comment: @jimjim Thank you! I'll check it out.

Comment: @Peter Yes... But can we define algorithmic undecidability for a more rigorous result?  Because I believe it has not been proven to be mathematically undecidable (I reference generalized Collatz Conjecture)..

Comment: @lonestudent The variant I mean is very general and it was proven that it cannot be algorithmatically decided. Hence there is no way to decide in general, whether a given variant has divergent sequences or nontrivial cycles. Study [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) article for more details.

Comment: @Peter Yes what I mean to say is that Collatz Conjecture's generalization is algorithmically undecidable.  I had read somewhere that algorithmic undecidability is a different concept than any Conjecture being undecidable by mathematical definition..I've read something like this..

Comment: If we accept the [church-turing thesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church%E2%80%93Turing_thesis) , then those concepts are equivalent. If we use a fixed theory (like ZFC) the concepts are in fact equivalent as long as we can program the theory (which can be done in the case of ZFC). By enumerating over all proofs and disproofs we will eventually solve the conjecture, if ZFC is able to do that.

Comment: Take a look at the $7x\pm1$ problem: https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.00908

Comment: See a picture of theoretical evolutions for $3x+1$,$4x+1$,$5x+1$,... when they behave randomly at https://mathoverflow.net/a/200126/7710. This indicates that for all $mx+1$ there should occur divergent trajectories for $m \gt 4$ *(while $m=4$ is of course only hypothetical)*

Comment: What is special about the multiple of three in this function is that the result is linearly increasing and there are local rules that eventually removes all the one's in the base $2$ expansion (except for the last one).

Comment: @DaBler the $7x\pm1$ problem is not exactly the same as the Collatz one. With the former problem we choose the $\pm$ sign to make the generated even number a multiple of $4$, which increases the average number of subsequent divisions by $2$ from two to three. This change enables a decrease to $1$ with a coefficient as large as $7$ instead of just $3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's odd, and it's less than $4$.

Odd --> Thus for each odd $n$, $3n+1$ will be even and we can do divisions by $2$.

Less than $4$ --> This is more subtle. When we generate an even number, on average among all even numbers two such divisions are possible. Thus we expect statistically, each odd number tends to be followed by a smaller odd number because $3<4$, favoring the conjecture that we always go down to $1$. Higher odd coefficients, greater than $4$, are not as cooperative.

Answer (score 1):

It's prime. That means the mappings it produces aren't related to scalings of a primes variant. It's also odd, and that is needed to hit even numbers. It being small, has the advantage of not needing a complex conditions for it to decrease easily.  $k=5$ has $kj+1$ needing $j\equiv -(5^{-1})\pmod {2^m}$ to decrease enough that division by $2^m$ or better occurs. This makes division by $8$ or higher power of $2$ a $1$ in $4$ or less occurence.